# Cannot turn web streaming into a function

Tags: python, python-3, picamera, sockets

I'm working on a project with my Raspberry Pi 0 and a camera. I'm writing my code in Python using the PiCamera module.
This file handles setting up the camera and Starting Web streaming. I had no clue on how to work with HTML and web streaming, so I followed the [example in the PiCamera documentation.](https://picamera.readthedocs.io/en/release-1.13/recipes2.html#web-streaming)

Here's my file (it's very similar with the example):

```py
import io
import picamera
import logging
import socketserver
from time import sleep
from threading import Condition
from http import server

class StreamingOutput(object):
    def __init__(self):
        self.frame = None
        self.buffer = io.BytesIO()
        self.condition = Condition()

    def write(self, buf):
        if buf.startswith(b'\xff\xd8'):
            # New frame, copy the existing buffer's content and notify all
            # clients it's available
            self.buffer.truncate()
            with self.condition:
                self.frame = self.buffer.getvalue()
                self.condition.notify_all()
            self.buffer.seek(0)
        return self.buffer.write(buf)

class StreamingHandler(server.BaseHTTPRequestHandler):
    def do_GET(self):
        if self.path == '/':
            self.send_response(301)
            self.send_header('Location', '/index.html')
            self.end_headers()
        elif self.path == '/index.html':
            content = SetupPage().encode('utf-8')
            self.send_response(200)
            self.send_header('Content-Type', 'text/html')
            self.send_header('Content-Length', len(content))
            self.end_headers()
            self.wfile.write(content)
        elif self.path == '/stream.mjpg':
            self.send_response(200)
            self.send_header('Age', 0)
            self.send_header('Cache-Control', 'no-cache, private')
            self.send_header('Pragma', 'no-cache')
            self.send_header('Content-Type', 'multipart/x-mixed-replace; boundary=FRAME')
            self.end_headers()
            try:
                while True:
                    with output.condition:
                        output.condition.wait()
                        frame = output.frame
                    self.wfile.write(b'--FRAME\r\n')
                    self.send_header('Content-Type', 'image/jpeg')
                    self.send_header('Content-Length', len(frame))
                    self.end_headers()
                    self.wfile.write(frame)
                    self.wfile.write(b'\r\n')
            except Exception as e:
                logging.warning(
                    'Removed streaming client %s: %s',
                    self.client_address, str(e))
        else:
            self.send_error(404)
            self.end_headers()

class StreamingServer(socketserver.ThreadingMixIn, server.HTTPServer):
    allow_reuse_address = True
    daemon_threads = True

def SetupPage():
    page="""\
    <html>
        <head>
            <title>Testing stream</title>
        </head>
        <body>
            <center><h1>Live Broadcast</h1>
            <img src="stream.mjpg" width="1280" height="720" /></center>
        </body>
        </html>"""
    return page


def SetupCamera():
    print('Initializing camera.')
    camera = picamera.PiCamera()
    camera.resolution = (1280,720)
    camera.framerate = 30
    camera.rotation = 90
    print('Camera initialized.')
    return camera

camera = SetupCamera()
output = StreamingOutput()
camera.start_recording(output, format='mjpeg')
print('RECORDING!')
try:
    address = ('', 8000)
    server = StreamingServer(address, StreamingHandler)
    server.serve_forever()
except KeyboardInterrupt:
    pass
finally:
    print('  TERMINATING!')
    camera.stop_recording()
    print('STOPPED RECORDING!')
    print('Closing...')
```

This code works and does the streaming perfectly. But I wanted to turn the last bit into a function, so I can import it in another file. Something like this:

```py
def StartStream():
    camera = SetupCamera()
    output = StreamingOutput()
    camera.start_recording(output, format='mjpeg')
    print('RECORDING!')
    try:
        address = ('', 8000)
        server = StreamingServer(address, StreamingHandler)
        server.serve_forever()
    except KeyboardInterrupt:
        pass
    finally:
        print('  TERMINATING!')
        camera.stop_recording()
        print('STOPPED RECORDING!')
        print('Closing...')

StartStream()
```

But now, it does not work. The website will display, but there will be no streaming. The console will present this output uppon running the file.

```
Initializing camera.
Camera initialized.
RECORDING!
<my ip> - - [19/Jun/2019 16:54:25] "GET /index.html HTTP/1.1" 200 -
<my ip> - - [19/Jun/2019 16:54:25] "GET /stream.mjpg HTTP/1.1" 200 -
WARNING:root:Removed streaming client ('<my ip>', 58487): name 'output' is not defined
```

Why does it not work? Is it simply not do-able? If so, how can I import this in another file?

Comment: This is just a Python programming question.  Nothing really to do with Raspberry Pi.

Comment: It looks like you got the scope wrong.  The `output` variable was global but used internal to some of your other functions.  When you put it into a function too, it was no longer global but rather local to the new function.  When the original function was called, it no longer had a definition for it.

Comment: I'm currently running into the exactly same issue as yours. Wonder if you find out any solution.

Answer (score 0):

I have been working in a similar area, and had the same issue. I use several modules, including one where I put all the classes.  I finally fixed this particular error by adding "output = StreamingOutput()" at the bottom of the module file that has the classes.  Of course, in my function I then had to reference it as classesModule.output